# Como encontrar conteúdo sem tag específica

Tags: html, css

Estou numa situação em que preciso encontrar conteúdo sem uma tag específica. É claro que qualquer conteúdo é envolvido por uma tag, nem que seja a `body` ou `html`. Com o exemplo fica mais claro o que preciso:

```
<div class='texto'>
<p>Essa imagem é muito bonita!</p>
<img src='imagens.png'/>
Foi tirada em Munique, Alemanha
</div>
```

No caso, preciso estilizar de **maneira igual** os dois textos, tanto o que está envolvido por um `p`, quanto o que está jogado diretamente na `div`. Porque quando preciso usar atributos no css como line-height ou outras coisas do tipo, a estilização não fica legal. Queria ver qual a melhor maneira de selecioanr esse conteúdo *solto* na `div`

Comment: De onde vem esse texto? não podes corrigir isso no servidor? ou no documento html diretamente?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exemplo : Toda formatação que a `div` pai tiver as filhas vão herdar.

```html
<div class='texto'>
<p>Essa imagem é muito bonita!</p>
<img src='imagens.png'/>
Foi tirada em Munique, Alemanha
</div>
<style>
.texto{
 font-size:20px;
 color: #006633;
 }
</style>
```